# How to populate a 64 bit register with duplicate byte values

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, masm

I'm doing some x64 assembly with Visual C++ 2010 and masm ('fast call' calling convention).

So let's say I have a function in C++:

```
extern "C" void fillArray(unsigned char* byteArray, unsigned char value);
```

The pointer to array will be in RCX and char value will be in DL

How can I fill RAX with values using DL such that if I were to `mov qword ptr [RCX], RAX` and print byteArray, all the values would be equal to 'char value'?

Please note that I'm not trying to do out-code my compiler, I'm just learning.

Comment: If you want to learn some MMX/SSE there are such instructions. But in this case it will probably be slower because it just for one value. SSE performs much better if you do calculations on many values simultaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you called your procedure 'fillArray', I assumed you like to fill a whole memory block with a byte value. So I did a comparision on different approaches. It is 32 bit masm code, but the results should be similar in 64 bit mode. Each approach is tested with both aligned and unaligned buffers. Here are the results:

```
Simple REP STOSB - aligned....: 192
Simple REP STOSB - not aligned: 192
Simple REP STOSD - aligned....: 191
Simple REP STOSD - not aligned: 222
Simple while loop - aligned....: 267
Simple while loop - not aligned: 261
Simple while loop with different addressing - aligned....: 271
Simple while loop with different addressing - not aligned: 262
Loop with 16-byte SSE write - aligned....: 192
Loop with 16-byte SSE write - not aligned: 205
Loop with 16-byte SSE write non-temporal hint - aligned....: 126 (EDIT)
```

The most naive variant using the following code seems to perform best in both scenarios and has the smallest code size as well:

```
cld
mov al, 44h   ; byte value
mov edi, lpDst
mov ecx, 256000*4  ; buf size
rep stosb
```

EDIT: It's not the fastest for aligned data. Added MOVNTDQ version which performs best, see below.

For the sake of completeness, here are excerpts from the other routines - the value is assumed to be expanded into EAX before:

Rep Stosd:

```
mov edi, lpDst
mov ecx, 256000
rep stosd
```

Simple While:

```
mov edi, lpDst
mov ecx, 256000
.while ecx>0
    mov [edi],eax
    add edi,4
    dec ecx
.endw
```

Different simple while:

```
mov edi, lpDst
xor ecx, ecx
.while ecx<256000 
    mov [edi+ecx*4],eax
    inc ecx
.endw
```

SSE(both):

```
movd xmm0,eax
punpckldq xmm0,xmm0    ; xxxxxxxxGGGGHHHH -> xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH
punpcklqdq xmm0,xmm0   ; xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH -> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
mov ecx, 256000/4   ; 16 byte
mov edi, lpDst
.while ecx>0 
    movdqa xmmword ptr [edi],xmm0    ; movdqu for unaligned
    add edi,16
    dec ecx
.endw
```

SSE(NT,aligned,EDIT):

```
movd xmm0,eax
punpckldq xmm0,xmm0    ; xxxxxxxxGGGGHHHH -> xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH
punpcklqdq xmm0,xmm0   ; xxxxxxxxHHHHHHHH -> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
mov ecx, 256000/4   ; 16 byte
mov edi, lpDst
.while ecx>0 
    movntdq xmmword ptr [edi],xmm0
    add edi,16
    dec ecx
.endw
```

I uploaded the whole code here http://pastie.org/9831404 --- the MASM package from hutch is required for assembling.

---

If SSSE3 is available, you can use `pshufb` to broadcast a byte to all positions of a register instead of a chain of `punpck` instructions.

```
movd    xmm0, edx
xorps   xmm1,xmm1      ; xmm1 = 0
pshufb  xmm0, xmm1     ; xmm0 = _mm_set1_epi8(dl)
```

Comment: Out of interest what CPU did you run these benchmarks on ? I'm interested to know whether SB/IB/Haswell would see similar benefits from using non-temporal stores ?

Comment: I used an AMD x4 640 CPU with DDR3-RAM clocked at 1333.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try running your code on a Haswell and see if it gives similar results.

Answer (score 12):

You can multiply by 0x0101010101010101 to copy the lowest byte into all other bytes (assuming the rest were all zero to begin with), it's slightly annoying because there is no `imul r64, r64, imm64` but you can could do this:

```
mov  rax, 0x0101010101010101 
imul rax, rdx                 ; at least as fast as  mul rdx  on all CPUs
```

If `rdx` is not of the required form (in other words, if it has some extra bits set), just add a
`movzx eax, dl` in front, and move the constant into RDX or another register.  (`movzx edx,dl` can't benefit from mov-elimination on Intel CPUs.)

If you don't like the code size (`mov r64, imm64` is already 10 bytes by itself), just stick that constant in your data segment.

Comment: That bit about the multiplication by constant is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: For future readers of the q/a: broadcasting a byte into an SSE register might be a better choice to set up for a memset (aka fillArray).  Using integer instructions to broadcast it to a 32b register first (e.g. with this `imul` trick), and then doing `movd` might make sense, or else use pshufb with an all-zero control mask (which you can generate efficiently with pxor aka `_mm_setzero()`).

Comment: (`_mm_setzero_si128()` is the full name of the intrinsic I meant.)

Answer (score 3):

Naïve way

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov bl, dl   ; input in dl
mov bh, dl
mov eax, ebx
shl ebx, 16
or  ebx, eax
mov eax, ebx
shl rax, 32
or  rax, rbx ; output in rax
```

So it might be slower than harold's solution

You can also look at the compiler's assembly output for the following code

```
uint64_t s;
s = (s << 8)  | s;
s = (s << 16) | s;
s = (s << 32) | s;
```

gcc 8.2 generates [the following output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAgnIVKVmdVp3EFwIyfNXLIhQQBsAFgB9AlUAMzwGBkDBBDxQgghvfQAOYNVkAEoPDgB2PktVQtUkvyCQwQcAEXSNfIsi1QqNaogmrQ1NVWSMwtzOwVqPBraWts0O1VpfHr7GwYKikdVWh3GtVVkuGZz%2B%2Bfqi4kwCMRY52TrcyuyvHwC08Mjo2PiuRJ9UkMzsvKGiks20ksIMhVhNuuodjVzr9CkCxhMpttdtCFoVDsdiKcoCU7gQMvD1pskWcLjkrpYPDiymEIlEALYiBhvFJpL4Un6o1Tok7pABUZgAHmZaMLRSLxWKAKoAGWle0u1wsVPutMCdMwdMER2ZBA%2B6Sy7LqDWV5T2DXVmu13F8glI6TtgjwAC9MKhQo0sij9mijjyBl6FZYpBlGNIAKxSUgsaRmSOoaTjXj8RqicT2OS0SMEGPBkMAaxAXH8BloAE4i/4uDlaGGzGZS75krJQ1J/JHo1JY6R41JI4IQGZSNnO8HSHBYEg0HSAA4RTBkCjA1AzufEEDAZJcUgPAjz/sQABGOdIB4UTGIAE9pJnSFP1foAPIsBhXkekLB01jABiSN/4Q7IAQeAAG6YP2b6YAKmDICIu7XpGPiYAwx4EM4dLwSGzBsCg/D8IweAHv2kAhqg05AagLDgQAtA%2BsiqFRoSgcQB6oFqVFMIIdJ9qmEh0Jh4btsePYCskvhUQEqjAMgILJAYXDLLghAkOoXCyPQqiaMus4/sQKlqT0iZ8LwWY5hk%2BaFsWOTJGGZZVrIZhWQEvjNshraCW%2BPZ9gOQ6mWOMCICgWmruQlBTtp84oFhwDBMQIgsHm24RLuxD7keb6niw56vjed6YI%2Bz6vl2H5fj%2Bx7/tBQGgeBXaQdBsG/jeiGuV2qF4OhUiZphX44UmvD4YR8AkWReAUdRtHcWIvG0PxUgRlGQnSCJYkSUoX7LKhcV5j0ECKUQukZnamkrjpelbBpuHGT5I5maQBaqQYon%2BFZOS%2BKWYavfW/gudIbbzR50heYOw6xiG44BWFwWLhDOkgHg0llolDDJalx4ZVl8G3su94EE%2BL5lRqJW/kVeAAZVYHHrVMFwR1CH6EhKFoRhjDdZwvUCAwBFERAQ3kZR0g0XRDFMSxbEcXS9GfuIxiyJUmVkxNaZ8S2c0dl2wmieJ/iqHDIJlgYZj6wp%2BB7Xp6lHeF%2B2qbIBkXTwJnXeZVYlmGOQu42YbWbQXDlmGLa/arcYA0I3nA7mLZcO5atB6HN1MY6FEgP4QA) with the result in rax

```
movzx   edi, dil      # s, c
mov     rax, rdi  # _1, s
sal     rax, 8    # _1,
or      rdi, rax    # s, _1
mov     rax, rdi  # _2, s
sal     rax, 16   # _2,
or      rax, rdi    # s, s
mov     rdi, rax  # _3, s
sal     rdi, 32   # _3,
or      rax, rdi    # s, _3
ret
```

As you can see, it's not very efficient since the compiler always uses 64-bit registers even when not necessary. So to make it easier for compilers to optimize just modify it like this

```
uint32_t s = (c << 8) | c;
s = (s << 16) | s;
return ((uint64_t)s << 32) | s;
```

Note that this is only for filling a single register like RAX with values using DL as you mentioned. For a big array it's better to use SIMD or other specialized instructions such as `repstos`, like how `std::fill` or `memset` is implemented. Both gcc and Clang are also smart enough to recognize `memset(&int64, bytevalue, sizeof int64)` and convert it to a multiplication by 0x0101010101010101 like above

Comment: `movzx ebx, dl` is always better than `xor ebx,ebx`  / `mov bl,dl`.  The XOR-zeroing doesn't avoid partial-reg merging penalties after writing BH on any CPUs, AFAIK, so it's bad on any Intel P6/SnB-family, but clever on AMD or Silvermont.  Other novel ways include `shrd ebx, edx, 8` twice, or four times, on CPUs with 1-cycle latency SHRD.  On modern CPUs with 3-cycle latency multiply, we're not going to beat that, though, at least for the 1->4 broadcast.

Comment: @PeterCordes why does `xor ebx, ebx` / `mov bl,dl` not work? [Your answer on fastest way to set zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/11322131) suggests that after zero idiom xor the registers upper 24 bits will be marked in some way as zero avoiding the stall. Whats different?

Comment: @Noah: `xor ebx,ebx` / `mov bl,dl` does work as a 2-uop version of `movzx ebx, dl`, as always.  But in the context of this answer, following it with `mov bh, dl` and then reading EBX still causes a partial-register stall. I was guessing that the reason for using xor/movb instead of movzx was an attempt to avoid partial-register merging penalties, but unfortunately there's no way to write AH and then read the full register without problems on P6-family or SnB-family.  I see how my earlier comment could lead to confusion though. :/

Comment: @PeterCordes ahh, was just thinking about it in terms of `xor ebx, ebx; mov bl, dl` + read from `ebx`. Yeah the write to `bh` does it :)